# Ubuntu does not update/upgrade

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I have a problem on my Linux, and every time I do a sudo apt-get update and then I want to do an apt-get update I get the following:

.....

```
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete libglib2.0-dev:amd64 (--configure): problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de libpango1.0-dev:amd64: libpango1.0-dev:amd64 depende de libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.59.2); sin embargo: El paquete `libglib2.0-dev:amd64' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete libpango1.0-dev:amd64 (--configure): problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de libcairo2-dev:amd64: libcairo2-dev:amd64 depende de libglib2.0-dev; sin embargo: El paquete `libglib2.0-dev:amd64' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete libcairo2-dev:amd64 (--configure): problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de libatk1.0-dev:amd64: libatk1.0-dev:amd64 depende de libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.31.2); sin embargo: El paquete `libglib2.0-dev:amd64' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete libatk1.0-dev:amd64 (--configure): problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de libatspi2.0-dev:amd64: libatspi2.0-dev:amd64 depende de libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.4.1-2); sin embargo: El paquete `libglib2.0-dev:amd64' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete libatspi2.0-dev:amd64 (--configure): problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de libgtk-3-dev:amd64: libgtk-3-dev:amd64 depende de libatk1.0-dev (>= 2.15.1); sin embargo: El paquete libatk1.0-dev:amd64' no está configurado todavía. libgtk-3-dev:amd64 depende de libcairo2-dev (>= 1.14.0); sin embargo: El paquete libcairo2-dev:amd64' no está configurado todavía. libgtk-3-dev:amd64 depende de libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.57.2); sin embargo: El paquete libglib2.0-dev:amd64' no está configurado todavía. libgtk-3-dev:amd64 depende de libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.41); sin embargo: El paquete libpango1.0-dev:amd64' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete libgtk-3-dev:amd64 (--configure): problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de libharfbuzz-dev:amd64: libharfbuzz-dev:amd64 depende de libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.19.1); sin embargo: El paquete `libglib2.0-dev:amd64' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete libharfbuzz-dev:amd64 (--configure): problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64: libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64 depende de libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.4.1-2); sin embargo: El paquete libglib2.0-dev:amd64' no está configurado todavía. libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64 depende de libatspi2.0-dev; sin embargo: El paquete libatspi2.0-dev:amd64' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64 (--configure): problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:amd64: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:amd64 depende de libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.37.6); sin embargo: El paquete `libglib2.0-dev:amd64' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:amd64 (--configure): problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar

Errors found while processing:

python3

devhelp

lsb-release

python3-lib2to3

python3-distutils

libglib2.0-dev-bin

python3-apt libglib2.0-dev:amd64

libpango1.0-dev:amd64 libcairo2-dev:amd64

libatk1.0-dev:amd64 libatspi2.0-dev:amd64

libgtk-3-dev:amd64 libharfbuzz-dev:amd64

libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:amd64
```

This is part of the errors I get. I am on version 20.04. If anyone can help me.

I have no idea what happened, I just installed PyCharm (A JetBrains tool for programming in Python) and had problems with python and the GTK library, I don't know if that is what caused these problems.

Comment: Python is an integral part of Ubuntu and is used for internal processes. Your installation may have installed an incompatible version of Python and deleted the working version.